# Is it possible to remove mysql table collation?

Tags: mysql, collation

In my mysql set up, tables and their columns are automatically given utf8_unicode_ci collation. However, there is one table where I want no collation.

How do you set that up? Also, is it possible to remove collation from a table?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the collation of a column using alter table, for example assuming your column is a `VARCHAR(40)`:

```
alter table YourTable modify YourColumn varchar(40) collate utf8_bin;
```

If you don't want any collation at all change the column type to binary, varbinary or blob:

```
alter table YourTable modify YourColumn varbinary(40);
```

You can also change the default collation of a table but it only affects columns you create afterwards.

Comment: Thank you Joni - I will have a play with that tonight.