# MySQL considers 'е' and 'ё' equal, how do I set it to consider them different?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a unique constraint on a `varchar` field. When I try to insert 'e' and 'ё' in two different rows I'm prompted with a unique constraint violation. Executing the following `select` shows that MySQL considers the letters equivalent in spite of their HEX values being D0B5 and D191 respectively.

```
select  'е' = 'ё',
        hex('е'),
        hex('ё');
```

Following a fair amount of Googling I came across [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34096) MySQL bug report which seems to deal with this issue. The very last response by Sveta Smirnova states that this behavior is by design and refers to the [Collation chart for utf8_unicode_ci, European alphabets (MySQL 6.0.4)](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_unicode_ci.european.html).

How do I tell MySQL that 'е' is not equal to 'ё' for query purposes and how do I change the unique constraint to take note of this fact?

Comment: If you don’t need any of the _features_ that collations offer for comparing letters, you could go with a BINARY value instead … http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-binary-op.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to check this answer:  [Is it possible to remove mysql table collation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288037/is-it-possible-to-remove-mysql-table-collation)

The behavior you're seeing is standard.  In most cases it produces the best results.  From a point of interest do you have an example of how this is causing a problem for you.  Have you found two words which match except for the [diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)?

Either way the only thing you can do about it is to change the collation.  This can be done at the server, database, table or even field level.

Rather than my duplicating the manual on how to do this; please follow this link:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html

There's a listing here of the different collations supported:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: I've run into a few words matches with different diacritics on a given letter but the word match that really had me confused was the one where everything matched except a Cyrillic lower case 'е' and an umlaut 'ё'. The Cyrillic lower case 'е' looks a lot like the standard Latin lower case 'e'.

Comment: I ended up adopting utf8 encoding in combination with utf8_bin collation, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that for an especific field you could add a duplicate of the column with a different collation for prevent this issue.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN `copiedColumn` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'binary' COLLATE 'binary';
```

Also, you can change the collation of your column if you don't need the your current collation in this field

ALTER TABLE yourTable CHANGE COLUMN yourColumn yourColumn VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'binary' COLLATE 'binary';